# lein deps fails on incanter cloned from github

Tags: clojure, incanter

Cloned incanter from github. When I try to do a lein deps, I get a bunch of errors:

```
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/clojure $ git clone https://github.com/incanter/incanter.git
Cloning into 'incanter'...
remote: Counting objects: 12328, done.
remote: Total 12328 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (12328/12328), 40.96 MiB | 402.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7077/7077), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/clojure $ cd incanter/
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/clojure/incanter $ lein deps
Could not find artifact incanter:incanter-core:jar:1.5.6-SNAPSHOT in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Could not find artifact incanter:incanter-io:jar:1.5.6-SNAPSHOT in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Could not find artifact incanter:incanter-charts:jar:1.5.6-SNAPSHOT in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Could not find artifact incanter:incanter-mongodb:jar:1.5.6-SNAPSHOT in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Could not find artifact incanter:incanter-pdf:jar:1.5.6-SNAPSHOT in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Could not find artifact incanter:incanter-svg:jar:1.5.6-SNAPSHOT in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Could not find artifact incanter:incanter-latex:jar:1.5.6-SNAPSHOT in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Could not find artifact incanter:incanter-excel:jar:1.5.6-SNAPSHOT in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Could not find artifact incanter:incanter-sql:jar:1.5.6-SNAPSHOT in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Could not find artifact incanter:incanter-zoo:jar:1.5.6-SNAPSHOT in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/clojure/incanter $
```

Not sure what the problem is. I have tried this at several different times to see if it has to do with network issues, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute the `script/install` to compile code & install everything into local maven repository...

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that incanter 1.5.6 is available on Clojars yet. e.g. https://clojars.org/search?q=incanter-core

Comment: Well, he's trying to build incanter locally.  But I guess he needs to build the incanter-* dependencies first?